# When using mutate() in dplyr, how to create a new column to be the sum or mean or several cells in the row without typing all the names?

Tags: r, dplyr, mean

Say I have 120 columns in the table, the last 100 of them are `"week1", "week2", ... , "week100"`. Can I create a new column and make it equal to the mean value of the 100 weeks?

I tried `mutate(table, mean_value = mean(num_range("week", 1:100)))`, and it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two approaches for doing this. For both of them let' say your data looks like this:

```
df = data_frame(var1 = rnorm(10), 
            var2 = rnorm(10), 
            othervar1 = rnorm(10), 
            othervar2 = rnorm(10),
            othervar3 = rnorm(10))
```

and that we want to calculate the mean of the variables that have in their name the string 'othervar':

```
to_aggregate = names(df)[grepl("othervar", names(df))]
```

**Approach 1: NSE**

The most elegant solution is probably using non-standard evaluation. First we create the formula for the mean:

```
agg_formula = as.formula(paste0(" ~ mean(c(", paste0(to_aggregate, collapse = ", "), "))"))
```

that dynamically creates the formula for the mean:  ~(othervar1 + othervar2 + othervar3)/3. Then we can use dplyr to go row by row and apply the formula:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(tmp_ID = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(tmp_ID) %>% 
  mutate_(.dots = setNames(list(agg_formula), 'res')) %>% 
  mutate(check_res = (othervar1 + othervar2 + othervar3) / 3) %>% 
  ungroup()

      var1       var2  othervar1   othervar2   othervar3 tmp_ID         res   check_res
     (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)       (dbl)       (dbl)  (int)       (dbl)       (dbl)
1  -0.32615666  0.4713765 -0.3915121 -1.06072106  0.09051817      1 -0.45390498 -0.45390498
2   0.57071669  1.3189079  0.8762870 -2.00557762 -0.44993910      2 -0.52640991 -0.52640991
3   0.24825279 -0.9491394 -2.1563560 -0.01378413 -0.22521368      3 -0.79845126 -0.79845126
4  -1.80198808 -2.2495440 -1.1170833  0.50966421 -0.56381476      4 -0.39041128 -0.39041128
```

**Approach 2: Melting**

The second approach is a bit less pretty (in my opinion) and it's melting first the dataframe:

```
library(reshape2)
df %>% 
   mutate(tmp_ID = row_number()) %>% 
   select(tmp_ID, contains("othervar")) %>% 
   melt(id.vars = "tmp_ID") %>% 
   group_by(tmp_ID) %>% 
   summarize(res = mean(value))

tmp_ID         res
(int)       (dbl)
1       1 -0.45390498
2       2 -0.52640991
3       3 -0.79845126
4       4 -0.39041128
```

and if you want you can then join back with the original data using left_join and 'tmp_ID' as key.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't fit perfectly into a pipeline, but how about:

```
weekdata <- select(table,week1:week100)
table %>% mutate(meanval=rowMeans(weekdata))
```

?